# Settings for ComboPooledDataSource with JDBCTemplate

Tags: c3p0

For accessing DB I have created datasource using com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource with following properties
`

```
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="200" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="25" />
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="3" />`
```

My dao class extends JDBCDaoSupport and above datasource is set into the JDBCDaoSupport which inturn provides JDBCTemplate for executing queries. I am not using any transaction manager. 
I have two questions now:

1. How the transaction in managed? Does JDBCTemplate itself creates the transaction before insert ?
2. If database is not available, Initializing c3p0 pool goes into infinite wait..I suppose there should be some property which I can set as a timeout for initialization of pool. 
   I tried         '
   `<property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="1" />`
   but not sure if this the correct way of doing it.

Comment: by default, c3p0 makes 30 attempts to contact the database [`acquireRetryAttempts` = 30 ] with a 1000 msec delay [`acquireRetryDelay` = 1000 ]. it doesn't try forever. however, unless you set `breakAfterAcquireFailure`= true, it will begin a new round of attempts whenever a new client comes asking for a Connection, so it might seem that way. i don't know anything about JDBCTemplate; maybe you should add a tag for that or Spring framework to the post to attract the attention of someone who might.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if JDBCTemplate works with ComboPooledDataSource... I was trying to configure it with c3p0 but it was giving me warnings, the connections were not returned to the pool and new connections were created for each request. It just flooded my Mysql server (and my application with Acquisition Attempt, Too Many Connections Error) 
Also I couldn't find anything on net regarding JDBCTemplate configuration except one tutorial on RoseIndia. following which produced those errors. 
I would suggest using SessionFactory (or maybe you can prefer core jdbc PreparedStatement and Resultset) for your db transactions. 
As far as Retry Attempts is concerned, I don't think c3p0 would go to infinite way by default configuration. You can use acquireRetryAttempts and acquireRetryDelay to set retry attempt time. 
From the mchange site itself :

> "When a c3p0 DataSource attempts and fails to acquire a Connection, it will retry up to acquireRetryAttempts times, with a delay of acquireRetryDelay between each attempt. If all attempts fail, any clients waiting for Connections from the DataSource will see an Exception, indicating that a Connection could not be acquired."
>   
>   It would be better to go through the reference documentation from mchange and configure your c3p0 as per your needs.
>   [mchange c3p0 reference](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration)